# Which pages is Magento FPC actually caching?

Tags: full-page-cache, enterprise-1.13

I'm wondering what Magento Enterprise FPC is actually caching. I read a couple times now that it is only caching category pages, product detail pages and CMS pages.

But what happens to the other pages/content?

- Header (since it a block)
- Homepage
- Footer (since it is a block)
- Wishlist (all pages)
- Gift registry (all pages)
- Customer Account (all pages)
- **Category Page / Search**
- Cart
- Checkout
- Success
- **Product Page Simple Product**
- **Page Configurable**
- **Product Page Grouped**
- **Product Page Virtual**
- **Product Page Bundle**
- **Product Page Downloadable**
- **Product Page Giftcard**
- **Static pages (CMS Pages)**
- BACKEND

So only the pages in "bold" get cached?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to cache the other pages, as they're user specific. Otherwise one user would see the other user's wishlist, not something you'd want :)

Comment: Thank you. Since this is the only answer I assume its correct!